# How to remove empty XML nodes using Java or XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, removechild, xmlnode

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<greatGrandParent>
    <grandParent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Fred</sibling>
            <sibling>Max</sibling>
            <sibling>Katie</sibling>
        </parent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Lindy</sibling>
            <sibling>Richard</sibling>
        </parent>
        <parent>
            <sibling />
        </parent>
    </grandParent>
    <grandParent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Steve</sibling>
            <sibling>Abbas</sibling>
        </parent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Kate</sibling>
            <sibling>James</sibling>
            <sibling>Ian</sibling>
        </parent>
    </grandParent>
    <grandParent>
        <parent>
            <sibling />
        </parent>
    </grandParent>
</greatGrandParent>
```

My requirement is - to remove an XML node if all of its child elements are empty. For instance, in the above shown XML,

- the 3rd parent of the 1st grandParent has no siblings. Hence, the sibling should be removed. And since the parent has no siblings, the parent should be removed as well from the XML. But, the grandParent would still exist since it has other parents with siblings.
- The only parent within the 3rd grandparent has no siblings. Hence, the sibling needs to be removed. And since the parent has no sibling, the parent should be removed as well. Since, the grandParent has no child elements(parent), the grandParent must also be removed from the XML.

Hence, the resulting XML must look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<greatGrandParent>
    <grandParent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Fred</sibling>
            <sibling>Max</sibling>
            <sibling>Katie</sibling>
        </parent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Lindy</sibling>
            <sibling>Richard</sibling>
        </parent>
    </grandParent>
    <grandParent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Steve</sibling>
            <sibling>Abbas</sibling>
        </parent>
        <parent>
            <sibling>Kate</sibling>
            <sibling>James</sibling>
            <sibling>Ian</sibling>
        </parent>
    </grandParent>
</greatGrandParent>
```

I'd be glad if somebody can suggest me a solution to do this using any Java API or XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following XSLT for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
                        <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To get an idea of how it works, execute the next XSLT that gives you an extra element on `grandParent` node, also read this little tutorial: http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="grandParent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <childValues><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></childValues>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Your XSLT works like a charm. Thanks @Mark. I'll wait for some more time for somebody to suggest me a solution to do the same using Java.

Comment: I'll be glad if you could also add an explanation to what it does. I understood that it tests for empty nodes within the XML, but I fail to understand how does it get rid of child and parent elements at the same time?

Comment: @abbasdgr8: First of all you have the identity template, which will go through all nodes of your XML file. Read this: http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity. The if condition tests if the current matched node has any value (direct value, child values etc.). If it has no value, skip the entire node (and it's childs)